# Why is there a discrepancy between Index Status and indexed from Sitemaps in Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

I've submitted a sitemap to GWT and things are starting to index as shown under the Crawl → Sitemaps menu. I've also confirmed indexing by doing a Google "site:" search.

However going to the Google Index → Index Status menu shows 0 pages indexed.

What is the difference between the Sitemap page's count of indexed pages and the Index Status count? There seems to be no simple way to see the total number of pages indexed. The only way is going through each individual sitemap index and summing up each individually (which is not possible as I have a lot of indexes).

Comment: I am assuming your site is still rather new. There will be a disconnect between stats for sitemaps and pages indexed. This answer explains some of this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74393/sitemap-xml-for-a-website-with-forum/74401#74401 Also please understand that Google Webmaster Tools is always at least 2 day behind and has been as far apart as 10 days before. Make sure you site can be crawled by Google by using Fetch as Google in WMT on a few pages and that your links are not blocking access to pages via search engines. This is usually a JavaScript problem.

Comment: Also make sure you are uploading xml files for the correct version of your site. Everything must match so if you verify your domain https ://www.example.com (secure and www) then the urls which you include in xml sitemaps must also be the same. Double check you are not trying to upload different URLs. You can also verify all the other versions http ://www.example.com, http ://example.com, https ://example.com to see if there are any discrepencies in the indexed count.

Comment: Check you robots.txt and see if you by mistake no indexed the whole site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But going to the Google index->Index status menu it shows 0 page indexed. What is the difference between the sitemap menu and the index status menu?

The index status menu lags behind the sitemap menu (about a week, sometimes more), but ultimately, they converge to the same value. If you are in a hurry, then compute the sum from the sitemap menu to have the latest estimation of what is indexed. Otherwise the index status will give you a good estimation, unless your site is really new (less than a month old).

Keep in mind that Google adds and removes pages from the index all the time. So, this figure can change all the time too.

Comment: The index status is now starting to show numbers. This is a new site and so it was indeed lagging behind.